# Combine UITabBarController with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I tried to use an "tabbed application" with a navigation bar in it. With the default the tab bar works fine, but I just can't gat a navigation bar. I found some stuff about pushing the navigation-bar and stuff like that, but all the stuff I found was some years ago, so don't gonna help me. And the recent stuff is outdated to, since iOS5 and the new version of Xcode..

Could anyone point me in the right direction to combine a to solve this problem?

Keep the following facts in mind please:

- I'm developing for iOS5
- I'm using Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve it programmatically.

Delete the reference to your main xib in [appName]-Info.plist

In main.m, load your delegate:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"myAppDelegate");
```

In the app delegate, load the tabBar, the navigation controller and the view in the navigationController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // create window since nib is not.
    CGRect windowBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    windowBounds.origin.y = 0.0;
    [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:windowBounds]];

    // View Controllers for tabController (one viewController per tab)
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // first tab has view controller in navigation controller
    FirstView *firstView = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstView];
    [viewControllers addObject:navController];

    SecondView *secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    [viewControllers addObject:secondView];    

    // create the tab controller and add the view controllers
    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    // add tabbar and show
    [[self window] addSubview:[tabController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The first view will have a navigation bar, the second one will be a plain view, right?

Comment: Right - only the first view is wrapped in a nav controller.  Other views in tab bar can be what u want them 2 b.

Comment: You're my hero! It works and it finally makes sense. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSMutableArray *arrayViewController = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
        [arrayViewController addObject:navigationController1];

        UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
        [arrayViewController addObject:navigationController2];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = arrayViewController;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 5 it is no longer tolerated to change the view controller for a tab (no problem before iOS5). The only accepted controller is that defined in IB for that tab. So it is neccessary to install a navigation controller on this tab and give his view the navigation bar. Then you can push or pop your desired views without changing the tab's controller.

Answer (score 1):

The basic theory is that you create a UITabBarController, and then put a UINavigationController inside that, and then put a UIViewController as the root view controller of the navigation controller.  bryanmac just answered with a good code sample.