# Pushing a navController not supported, in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Just created a new project and I have 4 view controllers which I add to `UINavigationController` like this:

```
WatchViewController *first = [[WatchViewController alloc] init];
BetViewController *second = [[BetViewController alloc] init];
Settings *third = [[Settings alloc] init];
Account *forth = [[Account alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navFirst = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:first];
UINavigationController *navSecond = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:second];
UINavigationController *navThird = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:third];
UINavigationController *navForth = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:forth];
```

Load them into an array:

```
NSArray *viewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:navFirst, navSecond, navThird, navForth, nil];
```

Load the tab bar and window:

```
self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:YES];

[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabController];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

All the view are just standard views. When I try and run the app it responds with :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
```

I can't figure out what I've missed. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
WatchViewController *first = [[WatchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WatchViewController" bundle:Nil];
BetViewController *second = [[BetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BetViewController" bundle:Nil];
Settings *third = [[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:Nil];
Account *forth = [[Account alloc] initWithNibName:@"Account" bundle:Nil];

/*Your View Navigation Stuff and your viewArray*/

self.tabController.viewControllers = viewArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create 4 navigation controllers. Controllers that are needed to navigate through should be assigned to `viewControllers` property in `UINavigationController` via `setViewControllers:animated:` method.

You should create 1 NavigationController and add array of 4 UIViewControllers.

A very good example is given here: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077613/uinavigationcontroller-simplest-example) and don't forget to look here [UINavigationClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I thought that might be the issue so I did try with only one navController. Thing is after failing I had a look online and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044668/combine-uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller which is virtually the same as I do (no nibs) but it crashes. I don't understand adding an array of views to a Nav Controller though. Example you have I don't think helps because of the TabBarController.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try `UINavigationController` inside `UITabBarController` by setting controllers in xib. It worked for me.

Comment: Nope, looked through that post twice and I'm doing exactly the same.

Comment: I want to avoid nibs, it should able to be done without them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had annoyingly subclassed UINavigationController instead of UIViewController. I hadn't picked up on it because if I didn't use the NavControllers the App would run fine, add the nav controllers and it broke. :(